# How to set IIS ARR request timeout time?

Tags: iis, iis-8, arr

I want to decrease the timeout time when my ARR server request to back-end server. In IIS settings interface, I cannot find any ARR settings configuration except for ARR cache.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr) is the only related information that I found:

> "So in this case we can clearly see that the ARR timeout was shorter than the execution of the request. Therefore, you would want to investigate whether this execution time was normal or whether you would need to look at why the request was taking longer than expected. If this execution time was expected and normal, increasing the ARR timeout should resolve the error."

As stated above, I can increase the ARR timeout. Who knows where to set it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To change the Server Farm Proxy timeout in IIS 8:

1. Click on your Server Farm in IIS.
2. Open Proxy.
3. Change Time-out value.
4. Click Apply.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809111135/https://theargylemvp.com/2013/02/12/using-iis-application-request-routing-arr-as-a-tmg-replacement/), we can change the default timeout of 30 seconds as mentioned at the end of the post.

Not sure if this can help for IIS 8.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Sorry for missing that out, this was my first answer posted and I was also not sure if this post will also help the person questioning or not as it was not for IIS 8.

Will take care of it next time :)

Comment: dead link - may want to revise

Answer (score 0):

in the IIS below the Sites, find your site and right click on it then open:
Manage Website > Advance Settings...

on that window find:
Behaivior > Limits > Connection Time-out

[image]